# Why rayon-based parallel processing takes more time than serial processing?

Tags: parallel-processing, rust, rayon

Learning [Rayon](https://github.com/rayon-rs/rayon), I wanted to compare the performace of parallel calculation and serial calculation of Fibonacci series. Here's my code:

```
use rayon;
use std::time::Instant;

fn main() {
    let nth = 30;
    let now = Instant::now();
    let fib = fibonacci_serial(nth);
    println!(
        "[s] The {}th number in the fibonacci sequence is {}, elapsed: {}",
        nth,
        fib,
        now.elapsed().as_micros()
    );

    let now = Instant::now();
    let fib = fibonacci_parallel(nth);
    println!(
        "[p] The {}th number in the fibonacci sequence is {}, elapsed: {}",
        nth,
        fib,
        now.elapsed().as_micros()
    );
}

fn fibonacci_parallel(n: u64) -> u64 {
    if n <= 1 {
        return n;
    }

    let (a, b) = rayon::join(|| fibonacci_parallel(n - 2), || fibonacci_parallel(n - 1));
    a + b
}

fn fibonacci_serial(n: u64) -> u64 {
    if n <= 1 {
        return n;
    }

    fibonacci_serial(n - 2) + fibonacci_serial(n - 1)
}
```

[Run in Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1b4f374369c4999b9c1c245e410884ef)

I expected the elapsed time of parallel calculation would be smaller than the elapsed time of serial caculation, but the result was opposite:

```
# `s` stands for serial calculation and `p` for parallel
[s] The 30th number in the fibonacci sequence is 832040, elapsed: 12127
[p] The 30th number in the fibonacci sequence is 832040, elapsed: 990379
```

My implementation for serial/parallel calculation would have flaws. But if not, why am I seeing these results?

Comment: If you are doing speed comparision, always use `--release` or the button Release in the upper left corner of the playground (under Debug)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the real reason is, that you create `n²` threads which is not good. In every call of `fibonacci_parallel` you create another pair of threads for rayon and because you call `fibonacci_parallel` again in the closure you create yet another pair of threads.
This is utterly terrible for the OS/rayon.

An approach to solve this problem could be this:

```rust
fn fibonacci_parallel(n: u64) -> u64 {
    fn inner(n: u64) -> u64 {
        if n <= 1 { 
            return n;
        }   

        inner(n - 2) + inner(n - 1)
    }   

    if n <= 1 {
        return n;
    }   

    let (a, b) = rayon::join(|| inner(n - 2), || inner(n - 1));
    a + b 
}
```

You create two threads which both execute the inner function. With this addition I get

```
op@VBOX /t/t/foo> cargo run --release 40
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.03s
     Running `target/release/foo 40`
[s] The 40th number in the fibonacci sequence is 102334155, elapsed: 1373741
[p] The 40th number in the fibonacci sequence is 102334155, elapsed: 847343
```

But as said, for low numbers parallel execution is not worth it:

```
op@VBOX /t/t/foo> cargo run --release 20
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.02s
     Running `target/release/foo 20`
[s] The 10th number in the fibonacci sequence is 6765, elapsed: 82
[p] The 10th number in the fibonacci sequence is 6765, elapsed: 241
```

Comment: those are internal tasks, not real threads, but pretty much the same result here.

Comment: The parallelization overhead is higher than the gains.

Comment: @chpio thanks for the particularization. Please feel free to [edit] my answer, I will happily accept it.

Comment: @chpio: Indeed, it's an overhead issue. Each task that is created needs to be scheduled, sent to a thread, etc... In general, parallelization is only worth it for coarse-grained parallelism.